# Struts2 passing two times in setter

Tags: java, jsp, struts2, setter

I'm facing an issue i can't understand (my struts2 knowledge not enougth).

I got in my JSP a form with :

```
<stags:form method="POST" action="foo" validate="false" theme="simple" id="form" name="form" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <stags:hidden name="A" />
</stags:form>
```

The first time I got the getter (getA) with empty string => OK
I post my form then show again the same JSP.
Here my issue :

1. I got setter due too post form. A = "" => OK
2. My alogorithm run and set le String A. A = foo => OK
3. Now i want to show the same JSP but I got another setter call before the JSP's getter. And this second setter call turn A to "" => KO

My java (over simplify code I know):

```
private String A = "";
public String execute() {
    System.out.println("before : " + A);
    A = "foo"; //(using "=" or "setA" same result)
    System.out.println("after : " + A);
    return SUCCESS;
}
public String getA() {
    System.out.println("getter : -" + A + "-");
    return A;
}
public void setA(String b) {
    System.out.println("setter : -" + b + "-");
    this.A = b;
}
```

struts.xml

```
<action name="Bar" class="package.Bar">
    <result>bar.jsp</result>
</action>
```

When I post, I got :

```
setter : --
before : 
after : foo
setter : --
getter : --
```

So in my JSP my input is always empty.
Is there any method called after execute or something like that ?

Comment: You are sending nothing to backend so its giving `""` String...  `<stags:hidden name="A" value="Check" />` then it will show A value as check

Comment: It does not solve my problem. If i use `value="Check"` A is always equal to "Check". It does not use the value changed by the `execute()`. I never used `value`, with the `name` struts knows that it need to use `getA()` to fill `value`.

Comment: How do you know if it's the same action is called? Before you populate the value a lot of code could be executed including getters and setters. All this code is hidden from the question and the question is unclear. You didn't give any clue how the setter is called. So voting this question as off-topic. It's impossible to answer the question with vague text.

Comment: I don't know how the setter is called. Struts do it itself when posting and creating the html page. That's why I don't understand why the setter is called two times. For me getter is called when dealing with jps to show html page and setter when posting.

Answer (score 0):

You should change your jsp to

```
<stags:hidden name="A" value="%{A}" />
```

so that your hidden filled get filled with new value from server.

**Note That**

It would be more prudent to use **lowercase letter** for variables.

According to a convention - variables begin with lowercase.

The fact that you are not following this rule may/or may not create a confusion with getters and setters and may/or may not brake your code.

So better (and in order to be on a safe side)

```
private String a = "";
public String execute() {
    System.out.println("before : " + a);
    a = "foo"; //(using "=" or "setA" same result)
    System.out.println("after : " + a);
    return SUCCESS;
}
public String getA() {
    System.out.println("getter : -" + a + "-");
    return a;
}
public void setA(String b) {
    System.out.println("setter : -" + b + "-");
    this.a = b;
}
```

and

`<stags:hidden name="a" value="%{a}"/>`

Comment: I try it to. But no change. The uppercase was just for the exmeple. But yes i use convention at maximum.

Comment: @Tyrael then you should use debugging, set break points etc in order to understand why is your setter called twice. I don't think we have enough information to help you. As you probably  understand it is not a normal behaviour for a setter to be called twice - so something is going on with your code...